# peakranger bcp segmentation fault

Tags: chip-seq

I'm running into a segmentation fault running peakranger's bcp on Arch Linux. Binaries were compiled from source just today. Any idea how I can prevent this?

```
$ peakranger bcp -d chip_seq/align_count/Sample_DNA_loA_h3k4me3/alignment/Sample_DNA_loA_h3k4me3.hisat2.bam -c chip_seq/align_count/Sample_DNA_loA_input/alignment/Sample_DNA_loA_input.hisat2.bam --format bam -o chip_seq/align_count/Sample_DNA_loA/call_peaks/bcp --gene_annot_file /data/sai/annots/musmus_GRCm38.94.gtf.gz --verbose
program version:          1.18
Data files:
 File format:             bam
 Sample file:             chip_seq/align_count/Sample_DNA_loA_h3k4me3/alignment/Sample_DNA_loA_h3k4me3.hisat2.bam
 Control file:            chip_seq/align_count/Sample_DNA_loA_input/alignment/Sample_DNA_loA_input.hisat2.bam
Qualities:
 P value cut off:         0.0001
 sliding window size:     500
 Read extension length:   200
Output:
 Regions:                 chip_seq/align_count/Sample_DNA_loA/call_peaks/macs2_region.bed
 HTML reports:            Enabled
 Plot region length:      6000
 Annotation file:         /data/sai/annots/musmus_GRCm38.94.gtf.gz

Reads statistics:

 Treatment reads +:       2125600
 Treatment reads -:       2113802
 Average read length:     20
 Control reads +:         7582218
 Control reads -:         7575995
 Average read length:     20
 Verifying reads...
Warning: JH584295.1 only contains reads in the positive strand. The chromosome is removed.
Warning: GL456382.1 only contains reads in the negative strand. The chromosome is removed.
Warning: No reads were found in GL456382.1 of the treatment dataset. The chromosome is removed.
Warning: No reads were found in JH584295.1 of the treatment dataset. The chromosome is removed.

Reads statistics after correction:

 Treatment reads +:       2125597
 Treatment reads -:       2113800
 Control reads +:         7582196
 Control reads -:         7575947

 Calling peaks...

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Reads were trimmed with trim galore and aligned with hisat2.

**Update 2018-10-29: additional information of input and machine**

```
$ samtools flagstat chip_seq/align_count/Sample_DNA_loA_h3k4me3/alignment/Sample_DNA_loA_h3k4me3.hisat2.bam
33521569 + 0 in total (QC-passed reads + QC-failed reads)
946323 + 0 secondary
0 + 0 supplementary
0 + 0 duplicates
5185725 + 0 mapped (15.47% : N/A)
0 + 0 paired in sequencing
0 + 0 read1
0 + 0 read2
0 + 0 properly paired (N/A : N/A)
0 + 0 with itself and mate mapped
0 + 0 singletons (N/A : N/A)
0 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr
0 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr (mapQ>=5)
$ samtools flagstat chip_seq/align_count/Sample_DNA_loA_input/alignment/Sample_DNA_loA_input.hisat2.bam
22508880 + 0 in total (QC-passed reads + QC-failed reads)
3359461 + 0 secondary
0 + 0 supplementary
0 + 0 duplicates
18517674 + 0 mapped (82.27% : N/A)
0 + 0 paired in sequencing
0 + 0 read1
0 + 0 read2
0 + 0 properly paired (N/A : N/A)
0 + 0 with itself and mate mapped
0 + 0 singletons (N/A : N/A)
0 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr
0 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr (mapQ>=5)
```

I tried this with two other input bam files and also hit a segfault.

Machine is a 36-core (72 hyperthread) workstation with 500GB of RAM.

```
$ peakranger --version
1.18
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.2.0
$ uname -r
4.18.3-arch1-1-ARCH
$ pacman -Q boost
boost 1.67.0-7
$ pacman -Q zlib
zlib 1:1.2.11-3
```

Comment: Thanks @Llopis, I've clarified the question and added information on the bam files and the machine.